# Returning pointer to character in C

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, return

I have a legacy code snippet that looks like:

```
const char *GetStr() const {
  return ("");
}
```

I am wondering whether this is a risky code as instead of returning a global character pointer, returning a local string literal?
For example, perhaps, the following code snippet is better.

```
const char *NullStr = "";
const char *GetStr() const {
  return NullStr; // instead of ""
}
```

What could be pros/cons?

Even the following implementation could be better:

```
const char *GetStr() const {
  static const char * lNullStr = "";
  return lNullStr;
}
```

Comment: Are you using C++ or C?

Comment: C++, but it's a part of legacy code, inherited

Comment: If you're really programming C++ (which I believe you do considering the `const` qualified function, don't tag C even for legacy C++ code) then you should not be using raw pointers for strings to begin with. The author of the function needs a smack on the head for writing it, in my not humble at all opinion. And with "modern" C++ there are alternatives for returning [optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) data. Finally, if pointers are really needed, IMO the correct way to return "null" would be a null pointer.

Answer (score -1):

Your first snippet is not strictly portable.

An alternative, which is, is:

```
const char *GetStr() const {
    static const char* s = "";
    return s;  
}
```

and also has the benefit that `s` is contained within the function.